# To access a specific cell and retrieve its content

Tags: tablesorter

How can I retrieve the content of a specific cell in a TableSorter object ? Let say I want to retrieve the content of cell[3,4] meaning the content of the third row and fourth column. I'm sure there is an easy way to do that...

Thanks !

FG

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) TableSorter works on a standard table

Assuming this is your table

```
<table id='myTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 0 / Cell 0</td>
    <td>Row 0 / Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 / Cell 0</td>
    <td>Row 1 / Cell 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So you should be able to get a specific cell by getting a reference to your table

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
```

Then access the specific cell by calling

```
var cell = myTable.rows[1].cells[0]
```

The contents of the cell should be accessible using

```
cell.firstChild.nodeValue; // returns "Row 1 / Cell 0"
```